# NameError: global name 'film' is not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Do not look for some strange words :)
When I run the program and I enter 1 then I enter film and push the button I get NameError: global name 'film' is not defined error :(

```
from tkinter import *
anaform=Tk()


anaform.resizable(False, False)


def verial():
    veri = giris.get()
    veri2=giris.get()
    veritabani = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\veritabani.txt", "a+")

    if veri == "1":
        giris.pack_forget()
        giris2.pack()
        veri2["text"] = film
        veritabani.write(film + "\n")


    elif veri == "2":
        etiket2.config(text="Yours films:",font=("Flux", 24, "bold"),fg="red")
        araetiket.config(text="_________________________",font=("Flux", 24, "bold"),fg="red")
        veritabani.seek(0)
        etiket3.config(text=veritabani.read(),font=("Corbal", 12))



etiket=Label(text="Make your selection: ", font=(24))
etiket.pack()

giris=Entry()
giris.pack()

giris2=Entry()
giris2.pack()


buton=Button(text="Gir!", command=verial, font=(24))
buton.pack(expand="yes", anchor="center")

etiket2=Label(text="")
etiket2.pack()

araetiket=Label(text="")
araetiket.pack()

etiket3=Label()
etiket3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Do not look for some strange words :)
When I run the program and I enter 1 then I enter film and push the button I get NameError: global name 'film' is not defined error :(

Comment: As far as I can tell you never assigned a value to the variable `film`. Is this all the code?

Comment: @Mike Yes this is all the code.film is bot variable, I'm putting the data to film

Answer (score 2):

This is because `film` has *not* been defined. Perhaps you want to put a value into film, so I would change the following:

```
...
veri2["text"] = film
...
```

To:

```
...
film = veri2["text"]
...
```

Comment: Its not work.I get TypeError: string indices must be integers error :(

Comment: There are more errors that remain but they have to do with the logic of your software itself. You are the only one who can fix that.